# Flickering animation in Safari

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image that is sticky and animated on scroll (adding styles via JS).

The reason for flickering is animating 2 properties: `left` (or `inset`) and `transform`. If I keep only one of them everything is ok, but I can't get the desired effect using only one of them.

Image styles:

```css
.img__container {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
}
img {
  position: absolute;
  transition: 0.5s all ease-in-out;
  object-fit: contain;
  aspect-ratio: 21/9;
  height: 100%;
}
```

The main reason for using `left` or `right` (`inset`) along with `transform` is positioning to the exact part of the image, so I can define if I'm showing N pixels from the right or left

I've tried some "fixes" from a community such as adding `-webkit-perspective`, `-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;`, `-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;` and adding `translateZ(0)` and all together, but nothing worked for me.

Comment: I don't know a guaranteed fix. But why use `left` and `transform` at the same time? Why don't you do the horizontal repositioning with `transform` as well?

Comment: @FrankConijn-SupportUkraine updated my question to clarify your thoughts

Comment: Could you show us the code that does something with left and transform. Preferably as a runnable snippet see https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example